# Is cublasSetMatrixAsync on the default stream blocking?

Tags: asynchronous, cuda

I would like to copy data from host to device and run some kernels in parallel. There seems to be conflicting information on whether running a cublasSetMatrixAsync function call will be blocking on the default stream?

I am seeing it block execution and am wondering what the correct way to use it is. Should cublasSetMatrixAsync be on the non-default stream? If so, is there an easy way for default stream to block if it needs the matrix on device for some kernel in the future?

Comment: Could you point to the relevant parts of NVIDIA's documentation that you think are in conflict?

Comment: A more or less educated guess is that it will show the same behavior as the normal CUDA memcopy functions, since I'm pretty sure that internally, the CUBLAS functions are just using the normal CUDA functions. The behavior of the latter was explained in detail in http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/sync_async.html (unfortunately, this overview section seems to be no longer contained in the more recent documentations...)

Comment: @njuffa I am looking at pg. 269 in "Professional CUDA programming" by Cheng, Grossman & Mckercher. The authors say that "If you want to overlap different CUDA operations, you must use non-null streams." but then later on that page suggest that cudaMemcpyAsync might be usable with the default stream.

Comment: @Marco13 thanks for the link. it is interesting, but doesn't seem to cover the relationship with streams.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it has blocking behavior.

From the [programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#implicit-synchronization):

> Two commands from different streams cannot run concurrently if any one of the following operations is issued in-between them by the host thread: 
>   ...
>
> • **any CUDA command to the default stream,**

`cublasSetMatrixAsync` is not exempt from this.

A general rule for CUDA concurrency is, if you want it, don't use the default stream.

> is there an easy way for default stream to block if it needs the matrix on device for some kernel in the future?

issue a `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`

That will force all cuda device activity, in any stream associated with that device, to finish before any subsequent commands, issued to any stream associated with that device, can begin.

Comment: Thanks for that. I guess my use case is a little more complicated as I have multiple host -> device transfers batched up (say matrices A, B, C...), and the compute is also batched up (opA, opB, opC...). I only want opB to wait for matrix B, opC to wait for matrix C, etc. Is there a way to match the synchronize calls in the default stream with the corresponding host -> device transfers?

Comment: Don't use the default stream.  If you want opB to wait for matrixB, then issue opB into the same stream that matrixB is being processed in.  CUDA activity issued to a given stream is always serialized.  If you want a host operation to wait for the device operations in a given stream, issue a `cudaStreamSynchronize()` instead.